# probably a python syntax error

Tags: php, python, forms, hash, cgi

just have some code dealing with hashes so here's a problem i ran into...

THE PYTHON:

```
import whirlpool
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
iR = form["iR"].value
print iR
iH = whirlpool.Whirlpool(iR)
pT = iH.hexdigest()

crosscheck = "8d8309ca6af848095bcabaf9a53b1b6ce7f594c1434fd6e5177e7e5c20e76cd30936d8606e7f36acbef8978fea008e6400a975d51abe6ba4923178c7cf90c802"

if pT == crosscheck:
    print "YAY u know da PASSWORD!"
else:
    print "fail."
```

THE PHP:
http://tekknolagi.co.cc/testme

What am I doing wrong with this? I think it's the CGI bit.

Comment: What is the value of: `pT`? Try printing it and see if it is indeed the same.

Comment: it fails to print pT...or nothing exists

Comment: just thought i'd add that iR doesn't exist either so it's more related to the cgi bit

Comment: For the record, it's terribly annoying the way you name variables. Single letters + camelCase = brainhurt

Comment: I suggest adding print statements for everything :) print `iR`, print `iH`, print `pT` (and make sure `pT` is ascii-encoded hex using lower-case characters too...)

Comment: iR = inputRaw
iH = inputHashed
pT = printedText

Comment: look. i printed everything but the variables DO NOT EXIST

Comment: And in what way does it not work? Error message? Variables do not exist before they are created. Afterwards they do exist.

Comment: no error messages - just a few modules were included in Whirlpool that didn't exist on webserver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Python script as CGI then you need to use it as CGI (i.e., set it as the value of the `action` attribute of the form) instead of invoking it directly.

Comment: really? this has always worked in the past... is it a syntax error?

Comment: and if i do so then it prompts me to download the `.py` file

Comment: Then your web server isn't treating it as CGI; see the documentation for your web server.